# Как писать в файл из нескольких параллельных процессов в Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Добрый День! Столкнулся с необходимостью ускорения выполнения одной тяжелой функции много раз и решил попробовать распараллелить её выполнение.

```
p0 = Process(target=post_searcher, args=(urls_for_process[0], words, depth, marks_and_models, filename))
p1 = Process(target=post_searcher, args=(urls_for_process[1], words, depth, marks_and_models, filename))
p2 = Process(target=post_searcher, args=(urls_for_process[2], words, depth, marks_and_models, filename))
p0.start()
p1.start()
p2.start()
p0.join()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

всё равно сначала запускается процесс 1, затем процесс 2 и тд. Как сделать так, чтобы все процессы запускались параллельно и функция отрабатывала для каждого из них в одно и то же время? функция `post_searcher` пишет в экселину результат работы алгоритма. Хочу чтобы писалось сразу из нескольких процессов. Пишу в эксель с помощью pandas

Comment: В файл в любом случае одновременно ничего писаться не будет. Как вы представляете одновременную запись на обыкновенном механическом жестком диске? Поэтому процессы будут ждать своей очереди на запись. Также ваша функция и так работает одновременно во всех процессах, какой "большей одновременности" вы хотите?

Comment: @m9_psy, про то, что запись в файл идет через кэш в ядре ОС  (если противным мы не озаботились специально) вы не забыли?

Comment: @avp, пользуясь каким-нибудь высокоуровневым интерфейсом знать не знаю ни про какие ядра. Наличие кеша как-нибудь повлияет на возможность параллельной записи? Я себе совсем не представляю, как вообще возможно параллельно в файл писать? Что будет, когда 2 процесса в одно и тоже место будут писать? Ничего хорошего. Как ни крути - записывалки, если их много должны как-то координировать свою работу, ставить mutex на файл, например. Плюс современные дисковые системы любят последовательную запись гораздо лучше случайной. Если писать в буфер, то потом оно все равно отправится на диск в один поток.

Comment: @m9_psy, нормальные системы уже давно (лет 30?) перед записью на диск переупорядочивают блоки файлового кэша (на этом уровне  об индивидуальных файлах и уж тем более процессах, которые  писали в файл, речь уже не идет) таким образом, чтобы минимизировать перемещение головок (т.н. *лифт*). Как раз для того, чтобы писать максимально последовательно. А простейший способ для нескольких процессов писать в один файл не мешая друг другу -- открывать файл на `append` (конечно, писать надо логически законченными независимыми фрагментами данных)

Comment: Кстати, физически запись проходит параллельно со счетной работой, по сути из обработчика прерываний ядра.

Comment: спасибо за объяснения) а такой вопрос, а что если, запись идет в эксельку и можно ли как-то разнести процессы, чтобы 1 писал с 0 до 1000 позиции, 2 писал с 1001 до 2000 и тд? но писали чтобы одновременно

Answer (score 1):

```
import multiprocessing

def post_searcher(*args):
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]    
    with open('file', 'a') as file:
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
            for result in pool.imap_unordered(post_searcher, args):
                file.write(str(result))
```

Comment: Описание сути решения словами могло бы улучшить ваш ответ (суть: писать в файл из одного процесса, собирая в нём результаты)